Gitea instance hangs when cloning over ssh
I have a gitea instance running on a DO droplet.
I edited my app.ini file to include:
DISABLE_SSH = false
SSH_PORT = 2222
SSH_LISTEN_PORT  = 2222
SSH_DOMAIN = git.stuylinux.org
START_SSH_SERVER = true
Then restarted gitea.service.

When I ssh into the server at port 2222 it returns:
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi there, axelKeizoStahl! You've successfully authenticated with the key named latptop_gateway, but Gitea does not provide shell access.
If this is unexpected, please log in with password and setup Gitea under another user.

I think that is right ^^
But then when I try to git clone (after adding my pub key of course), it just outputs nothing, it seems to be hung:
~/tmp ❯ git clone ssh://stuylinux_admin@git.stuylinux.org:2222/axelKeizoStahl/dwl.git
Cloning into 'dwl'...

Finally, it returns:
ssh: connect to host git.stuylinux.org port 2222: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Thanks for the help, let me know if you want more information.
I was expecting to just clone the repo, like with https but wiht no password. I did upload my public key and all that.
EDIT:
I think I've found the issue, I'm just not sure what it means.
Actually, when I ssh to git.stuylinux.org, it doesnt work, but when I ssh to the ip addr that that domain points to, it works.
I’m not sure why this is. I turned off cloudflare proxy in case it was that, otherwise I’m really not sure.
